# After script Geocoder form is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two fields for results, 1 field for input: address.  After clicking on the button, convert() is being called.

It checks googleapi for the longitude and latitude of the given address and then sets the (normally hidden) two fields with the found values.

After that the form submits, it throws out the values just being set.  For a split moment, before submits takes place, you see the fields are being set with the right values, and after submit the values are gone.

Its hard to explain how I know that, because this is just html but it's being handled by some sort of asp-solution, that remembers the values of a field and holds on to it. But in this example, if you remove the submit button and replace it for a non submit element, after click the script works and the fields are being set.

So why, are the values of the field not being submitted to the server?

Again, the values are set first, and than, the form is being sumbitted.

Best regards,
Simon

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBW2VZup4f6ykbp-bdoNeuedGpFHv8MPfM"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function convert(){
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address=ftForm.address.value;geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
ftForm.latitude.value = latitude;ftForm.longitude.value = longitude;} 
}); 
} 
</script>

<form method="post" name="ftForm">
lat<input type="text" name="latitude" value=""><br>
long<input type="text" name="longitude" value=""><br>
<BR><BR><BR><INPUT TYPE="text" name="address" value="norway">
<button onclick="convert();">Submit</button></form>
```

Comment: where is your server link, your api or method which is saving data into db?

Comment: neither you have mentioned it into action tag of the form neither you have use ajax request into your js convert function